# spark.sql.datetime.java8API.enabled=true doesn't map dateType to java.util.LocalDate by Encoders.bean(Association.class)

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to fill a Business Object `Association` with `LocalDate` members :

```java
/**
 * Renvoyer la date de déclaration de création (date de dépôt du dossier en Préfecture).
 * @return Date de déclaration de création (date de dépôt du dossier en Préfecture).
 */
public LocalDate getDateCreation() {
   return this.dateCreation;
}

/**
 * Fixer la date de déclaration de création (date de dépôt du dossier en Préfecture).
 * @param dateCreation Date de déclaration de création (date de dépôt du dossier en Préfecture).
 */
public void setDateCreation(LocalDate dateCreation) {
   this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
}
```

According to the documentation of Spark 3.x, I've sat the property `spark.sql.datetime.java8API.enabled=true`

```
hadoop.tmp.dir=/data/tmp
java.io.tmpdir=/data/tmp
spark.app.name=Config Associations (test)
spark.app.startTime=1630560867857
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/tmp
spark.driver.memory=2g
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/tmp
spark.executor.memory=1g
spark.home=/opt/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7
spark.local.dir=/data/tmp
spark.logConf=true
spark.master=local[12]
spark.sql.datetime.java8API.enabled=true
spark.sql.legacy.allowHashOnMapType=true
```

But the mapping operation fails :

```java
public Dataset<Association> toDatasetAssociations(Dataset<Row> rows) {
   Objects.requireNonNull(rows, "Le dataset des associations ne peut pas valoir null.");
      
   return rows.map((MapFunction<Row, Association>)row -> {
      Association a = new Association();

      /** filling members values */

      return a;
         
   }, Encoders.bean(Association.class));
}
```

being unable to compile its generated source :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 1710, Column 41: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 1710, Column 41: Unknown variable or type "java.time.LocalDateTime$.MODULE$"
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2410)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2380)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.compile(CodeGenerator.scala:1351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:1277)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SafeProjection$.createCodeGeneratedObject(Projection.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SafeProjection$.createCodeGeneratedObject(Projection.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CodeGeneratorWithInterpretedFallback.createObject(CodeGeneratorWithInterpretedFallback.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SafeProjection$.create(Projection.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$Deserializer.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$Deserializer.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:173)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsList$1(Dataset.scala:2977)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3687)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3685)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectAsList(Dataset.scala:2976)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.association.AssociationWaldecDataset.toAssociations(AssociationWaldecDataset.java:525)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.association.AssociationService.obtenirAssociations(AssociationService.java:45)
    at fr.ecoemploi.spark.dataset.association.AssociationsServiceIT.associationsRegistreNational(AssociationsServiceIT.java:54)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 1710, Column 41: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 1710, Column 41: Unknown variable or type "java.time.LocalDateTime$.MODULE$"
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:1415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1497)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    ... 102 common frames omitted
```

and fails on a messge : "*Unknown variable or type "java.time.LocalDateTime$.MODULE$*"

(I cannot show the line failling in the generated source, that is truncated to 1000 lines. If it's needed for understanding and you have a tip to do so, please tell me).